# Error: Calling js method onCreate failed in nativescript angular app

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I followed the steps provided in [here](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/how-to-build-a-pwa-an-ios-app-and-an-android-app-from-one-codebase) for android/ios app using nativescript + angular but I am getting below error when the app opens in the emulator.

I am sharing the root package.json.

I am not able to find where I have mistake. Can someone please help.

[image: Error Screen]

[image: package.json]

Comment: It must be some minor issue within your code, try running without `--bundle` option which may give you a better error log. Also try to post the error log as text rather image.

Comment: It works fine for below configuration - "name": "Checklist",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.Checklist",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.0.0"
    }
  }

Comment: @Baskar whats the version for tns-core-mdules? Should it be same as tns-andoid version?

Comment: @AkshayaJeevan Below are the versions "nativescript-angular": "~7.0.0", "tns-core-modules": "~5.0.0",

Comment: @AkshayaJeevan Also tested with "tns-core-modules": "^5.1.1", "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.1.0"
    } using Android emulator. Used commands tns run android --bundle to test.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, upgrade node.js from 8 to 10, removing node modules & hooks & webpack config file then reinstalling helped